Creating an Excel file with dynamic dropdowns using Python
I need to create an Excel file using Python that has two columns: "endpoint" and "source". The "endpoint" column should have a dropdown list with options 1 and 2. The "source" column should have a dynamic dropdown list that depends on the value selected in the "endpoint" column.
Here's the logic I want to implement:

If the user selects 1 as the endpoint, the source dropdown should show "auto" and "checklist" as options.
If the user selects 2 as the endpoint, the source dropdown should show "osvGrid" and "rcu" as options.
To achieve this, I plan to create a separate sheet with two columns: one for the endpoint values (1 and 2) and another for the corresponding source values ("auto" and "checklist" for 1, and "osvGrid" and "rcu" for 2). Then, I want to use a formula in the main sheet to populate the source dropdown based on the selected endpoint value.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this using Python.
Additional details:
I want to create a new Excel file from scratch using Python.
I'm open to using any Python library that can help me achieve this.
I'd appreciate any examples or code snippets that can help me get started.

import openpyxl
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation

# Create a new workbook and select the active sheet
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

main_sheet = wb.active
main_sheet.title = "Main"

# Create a new sheet to store named ranges (not necessary to be visible)
data_sheet = wb.create_sheet("Data")

# Define named ranges for source options
wb.create_named_range('SourceOptions1', data_sheet, 'A1:A2')
wb.create_named_range('SourceOptions2', data_sheet, 'A3:A4')

# Populate the data sheet with options
data_sheet['A1'] = 'auto'
data_sheet['A2'] = 'checklist'
data_sheet['A3'] = 'osvGrid'
data_sheet['A4'] = 'rcu'

# Add Endpoint dropdown in the main sheet
endpoint_validation = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"1,2"')
main_sheet.add_data_validation(endpoint_validation)
endpoint_validation.add('A2:A100')  # Adjust the range as needed

# Save the workbook
wb.save("dynamic_dropdowns_fixed.xlsx")



The below code works:
Logic - Same as mentioned in question.
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation

# Create a new workbook and select the active sheet
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

main_sheet = wb.active
main_sheet.title = "Main"

# Create a new sheet to store named ranges (not necessary to be visible)
data_sheet = wb.create_sheet("Data")

# Define named ranges for source options
wb.create_named_range('SourceOptions1', data_sheet, 'A1:A2')
wb.create_named_range('SourceOptions2', data_sheet, 'A3:A4')

# Populate the data sheet with options
data_sheet['A1'] = 'auto'
data_sheet['A2'] = 'checklist'
data_sheet['A3'] = 'osvGrid'
data_sheet['A4'] = 'rcu'

# Hide the Data sheet
data_sheet.sheet_state = 'hidden'

# Add Endpoint dropdown in the main sheet
endpoint_validation = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"1,2"')
main_sheet.add_data_validation(endpoint_validation)
endpoint_validation.add('A2:A100')  # Adjust the range as needed

# Add dynamic Source dropdown based on selected Endpoint
for row in range(2, 101):  # Adjust the range as needed
    # Use INDIRECT to point to the correct named range
    source_validation = DataValidation(type="list", formula1=f'=INDIRECT("SourceOptions" & A{row})')
    main_sheet.add_data_validation(source_validation)
    source_validation.add(f'B{row}')

# Save the workbook
wb.save("dynamic_dropdowns_fixed.xlsx")

